# Need faster archiving+compression of folders in .zip instead of .tar extension

Tags: linux, compression, zip, 7-zip, tar

I have a folder inside which are sub-folders and files. We currently use [7za](https://linux.die.net/man/1/7za) to **archive+compress** in the **.zip** file extension. Specifically, following is the command that we use:

```
/usr/libexec/p7zip/7za a -y -p123 -tzip finalzip.zip /var/software/data/
```

The problem is that this is quite slow in large size of data so we need to have a faster **archiving+compression**. Also, since we require the file to be compatible with windows, the file format should possibly be in **.zip** format. Currently, we don't specify a compression method in our command, thus I suppose [default](https://www.gpsoft.com.au/help/Opus10/index.html#!Documents/7z_Options.htm) compression method used is **LZMA**.

I researched parallel compression methods like **lbzip2, pbzip2, pigz** etc. but as far as I know, they are single file compression methods and doesn't work with folders but work with **tar** thus the file extension of the final file created is either **.tar.gz** or **.tar.bz2** which is not what we want. That should be our last option.

Thus, are there any tweaks in **switches** that can make it faster, or is there a better **archiver+compressor** than **7za**? Does the choice of archiver we use make any difference, or, does it largely depend on the compression method?

The help option in 7za includes following switches:

```
  -m{Parameters} : set compression Method
  -mmt[N] : set number of CPU threads
```

But is there any parallel compression method that it supports to decrease the time by a significant amount? Also, **-mmt** flag defaults to '**on**', thus, including the flag in our command didn't make any difference.

Comment: Have you tried running with `mmt=32` (use 32 threads)? (note, mmt isn't compatible with all compression types).

Comment: Large amounts of data; I'd wager that the bottleneck is **read** and **write** operations rather than compression algo' speed.

Comment: @spikey_richie My machine has 6 cores and 1 thread per core as shown by the command 'lscpu'. The 'htop' command shows that there are 10 processes created when -mmt flag is greater than 10. The number of processes doesn't exceed 10 (idk where this value came from).

Comment: You may want to start by checking the system resources while archiving to get an idea if your bottleneck is CPU or disk speed.